# Extra border is appearing in my dropdown list

Tags: html, css

I am developing dropdown component when I am styling the component using list using property bottom:-5px; then it also create a white border at bottom with my menu list.

`

```
.dropdown-options{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-5px;
    left:0px;
   transform: translateY(100%);
   width:100%;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 0px 0px 16px 16px;
}
```

The above code is my dropdown option list class and it creates an extra white border at bottom. how can avoid this extra bottom border?

Comment: Can you add a snippet to the question which reproduces the problem? Currently we can only guess your structure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.